# Dynamic and controlled component in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to dynamically generate controlled input components.

`data` is an array of object, which has following form:

```
data = [{obj1}, {obj2}, ...] // length not fixed
```

After `data` is loaded, it triggers `useMemo` and `useEffect` as below:

```
const [row, setRow] = useState([]);

const onContentChange = e => {
  const currentRow = [...row]
  currentRow[e.target.dataset.idx][e.target.className] = e.target.value
  setRow(currentRow)
}

useEffect(() => {
  const arr = []
  data.forEach(obj => {
    arr.push({
      content: obj.content
    })
  })
  setRow(arr)
}, [data])

const mData = useMemo(() => {
  const retArr = []
  data.forEach( (obj, i) => {
    retArr.push({
      content: (
        <input
          type="text"
          className="content"
          name={`content-${i}`}
          id={`content-${i}`}
          data-idx={i}
          onChange={onContentChange}
          value={row[i].content} // Error
        />
      )
    })
  })
  return retArr;
}, [data])
```

However, `row[i]` is empty at that moment. Maybe `useRow` function in `useEffect` is executed after `factory` of `useMemo` done.

Since there is a callback at `useEffect`, is there any way to control order of `useEffect` and `useMemo`?

Any other opinions are appreciated!

Comment: You really should learn to use `.map()` instead of declaring an array and `.push()`ing into it with `.forEach()`.

Comment: `value={row[i]?.content} `

Comment: use .map for the cases when the rows have length 0

Comment: Any reason for using `map` instead of `forEach`? AFAIK, `map` uses more array assignment than `forEach` which causes much slower execution.